# String concatenation after DISTINCT result selected

Tags: oracle, distinct, nsxmlparser

I have below query:

```
SELECT xmlagg(xmlparse(content RESULTS || '|' wellformed) ORDER BY RESULTS).getclobval() AS RESULTS 
FROM
(
  SELECT distinct ' '   || result|| ' - '   || result_final || ' xxx' as RESULTS from myTable where ID = '123456'
);
```

Currently the " xxx" will append at the end of each result_final, how can achieve by concatenating it to the very beginning of the final string of the query?

```
' xxx'|| RESULTS
```

With condition, above concatenation should only take place when result=x, else only RESULTS should be printed.

Comment: Do it in the outer query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move that string in front of the "result" not behind it.

Though, as additional condition should be met, use your current query (without 'xxx') as a subquery and apply condition via `CASE`.

With dummy sample data:

```
SQL> DESC mytable
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 RESULT                                             CHAR(1)
 RESULT_FINAL                                       CHAR(1)
 ID                                                 CHAR(6)

SQL> SELECT * FROM mytable;

R R ID
- - ------
x y 123456

SQL> SELECT CASE
  2            WHEN TO_CHAR (results) = 'x' THEN ' xxx' || results
  3            ELSE results
  4         END AS results
  5    FROM (SELECT XMLAGG (XMLPARSE (CONTENT RESULTS || '|' WELLFORMED)
  6                         ORDER BY RESULTS).getclobval () AS RESULTS
  7            FROM (SELECT DISTINCT
  8                         ' ' || result || ' - ' || result_final AS RESULTS
  9                    FROM myTable
 10                   WHERE ID = '123456'));

RESULTS
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 x - y|

SQL>
```

Comment: thanks, getting error on first line
ORA-00904: "RESULTS": invalid identifier

Comment: You shouldn't, as "results" in the 1st line just uses "results" alias from the 3rd line.

Comment: Thanks, it served  part of my solution, let's take a better example, I have the condition
WHEN results LIKE '%Duplicate%' THEN ' xxx' || results
But I do not want '%Duplicate%' being selected from the inner query, the "results" in outer query should auto discard any '%Duplicate%' and just concatenate with ' xxx' in front of the String.